# Groovy - Append values to variables in a string

Tags: grails, groovy

Lets assume I have a domain class called Template that looks somewhat like this:

```
class Template{
 String subject
 ...
}
```

I save an instance of this class:

```
Template t=new Template(subject:'Hello ${name}').save()
```

Now, I fetch this instance inside a method as follows:

```
def render(Long id){
  String name='foo'
  Template t= Template.get(id)
  println t.subject
}
```

> I want the "println t.subject" to be printed as "Hello foo". What I get is "Hello ${name}". 
>   I want t.subject to dynamically replace the value of variable name - "foo" in place of ${name}.

Can this be achieved in groovy? 
I cannot find any documentation of how to do this, or why this cannot be done.

Update:

I tried this on my GroovyConsole.

```
class Entity{
    String name
}

class Template{
    String name
    String subject
}

String renderTemplate(Template template, Entity entity){ 
   return template.subject
}

Entity e = new Entity(name:'product')
Template template=new Template(name:'emailTemplate',subject:'Product ${e.name}')

renderTemplate(template,e)
```

The Output I got was:

> Result: Product product

Comment: Possibly because you should be using messages.properties and gsps to render a template rather than using a db to act as a template :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. That is a solution i'm aware of. But i'm specifically trying to achieve the above as a use case.

Comment: Are you sure you have `new Template(subject:"Hello ${name}")` and not `new Template(subject:'Hello ${name}')`?  The double quotes are significant.  The behavior you are describing does not make sense and almost isn't possible.

Comment: Jeff. sorry i missed this comment. and yes. it was a single quotes. I apologize for the misleading led due to the single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Template {
  String subject
  // ...
}

Template t = new Template(subject: 'Hello, ${name}').save()
```

**Important:** Use single quotes in 'Hello, ${name}' or you will get an error.

```
def render(Long id) {
  String name = "world"
  Template t = Template.get(id)

  ​def engine = new groovy.text.GStringTemplateEngine()

  def subject = engine
    .createTemplate(t.subject)
    .make(name: name)​

  println subject
}
```

Comment: I got it to work using the GStringTemplateEngine. Thanks Vladimir. Sorry for all the confusion surrounding the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong with the code shown.  You have this:

```
class Template{
    String subject
    ...
}
```

Then you have this:

```
Template t=new Template(subject:"Hello ${name}").save()
```

The Groovy String assigned to the `subject` property will be evaluated as soon as you assign it to `subject` because `subject` is a `String`.  The actual value will depend on the value of the `name` property that is in scope when that code executes.

Later you have this:

```
def render(Long id){
    String name="foo"
    Template t= Template.get(id)
    println t.subject
}
```

It looks like you are wanting that local `name` property to be substituted into a Groovy String that has been assigned to `t.subject`, but that isn't how Groovy works.  `t.subject` is not a Groovy String.  It is a `String`.

Separate from that you comment that when you `println t.subject` that the output is `"Hello ${name}"`.  I don't think that is possible, but if that is what you are seeing, then I guess it is.

Comment: okay yes Jeff, that makes sense. It is not a Groovy String. It is a String. So can this String be converted to a Groovy String so as to have the value of the variable "name" be replaced by the variable name?

Comment: Yes, but is a bad idea and would rely on a somewhat complicated solution.  A better idea would be to introduce a dynamic property, or depending on the details, possibly just have a method that accepts a variable as an argument and returns a String that includes that.

Comment: I agree Jeff. That would be a simpler solution. If only I could make that call. Anyway, I got it to work with Vladimir's solution of using the 'GStringTemplateEngine'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `transient` property to emulate the required behavior:

```
class Template{
  String subject
  String getSubjectPretty(){ "Hello $subject" }
  static transients = ['subjectPretty']
}
```

Then you can use:

```
println Template.get(1).subjectPretty
```

Comment: In his code example he is trying to have a variable in a different scope somehow be inserted in the value of `description`.  That is a different scenario than you are expressing.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown his `render()` code is really misguiding: `String name="foo"` belongs rather to saving block. I guess, that your point about single quotes would solve the issue, but maybe he ment something else...

Comment: Right.  It is hard to say.  There are several things in the question that don't make sense.